# Casting Benefits even if spell is countered

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Playing [Sauron, Lord of the Rings](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sauron%2C%20Lord%20of%20the%20Rings). When cast you amass Orc 5 and return a creature from your graveyard. Since that triggers when cast will you get the two other creatures even if the spell is counted?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. Because the abilities triggers “when you cast”, that triggered ability goes on the stack immediately after Sauron goes on the stack; before opponents would even have a chance to counter Sauron. Once it is on the stack, it makes no difference if Sauron is countered or not.